# Java GUI printing blank page

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm working with a Java GUI and I want to get a single panel to print.  I get the prompt to come up, and I get something to print, but the problem is that something is just a blank page.

Below is all the relevant code:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, Printable {
```

...

```
public void print(){
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this);
        if(job.printDialog()){
            try{
                job.print();
            }catch(PrinterException e){
                System.err.print("Print failed: " + e);}

        }
    }
```

...

```
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {
        if(pageIndex > 0){
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
        this.setDoubleBuffered(false);
        this.paint(g);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;

    }
```

And then in another object which calls the function:

```
if(evt.getSource() == btn_print){

    p.print();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public class PrintView extends FrameView implements Printable,ActionListener{

public PrintView(SingleFrameApplication app) throws PrinterException {
    super(app);

    initComponents();

    jButton1.addActionListener(this);


    // status bar initialization - message timeout, idle icon and busy animation, etc
    ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
    int messageTimeout = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.messageTimeout");
    messageTimer = new Timer(messageTimeout, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            statusMessageLabel.setText("");
        }
    });
    messageTimer.setRepeats(false);
    int busyAnimationRate = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.busyAnimationRate");
    for (int i = 0; i < busyIcons.length; i++) {
        busyIcons[i] = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.busyIcons[" + i + "]");
    }
    busyIconTimer = new Timer(busyAnimationRate, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            busyIconIndex = (busyIconIndex + 1) % busyIcons.length;
            statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[busyIconIndex]);
        }
    });
    idleIcon = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.idleIcon");
    statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
    progressBar.setVisible(false);

    // connecting action tasks to status bar via TaskMonitor
    TaskMonitor taskMonitor = new TaskMonitor(getApplication().getContext());
    taskMonitor.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
            if ("started".equals(propertyName)) {
                if (!busyIconTimer.isRunning()) {
                    statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[0]);
                    busyIconIndex = 0;
                    busyIconTimer.start();
                }
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            } else if ("done".equals(propertyName)) {
                busyIconTimer.stop();
                statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                progressBar.setValue(0);
            } else if ("message".equals(propertyName)) {
                String text = (String)(evt.getNewValue());
                statusMessageLabel.setText((text == null) ? "" : text);
                messageTimer.restart();
            } else if ("progress".equals(propertyName)) {
                int value = (Integer)(evt.getNewValue());
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setValue(value);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Action
public void showAboutBox() {
    if (aboutBox == null) {
        JFrame mainFrame = PrintApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
        aboutBox = new PrintAboutBox(mainFrame);
        aboutBox.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
    }
    PrintApp.getApplication().show(aboutBox);
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
    jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
    jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    javax.swing.JMenu helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    statusPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    javax.swing.JSeparator statusPanelSeparator = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    statusMessageLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    statusAnimationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    progressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

    mainPanel.setName("mainPanel"); // NOI18N

    org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(print.PrintApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(PrintView.class);
    jButton1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jButton1.text")); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setName("jButton1"); // NOI18N

    jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));
    jPanel1.setName("jPanel1"); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel1.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setName("jLabel1"); // NOI18N

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" }));
    jComboBox1.setName("jComboBox1"); // NOI18N

    jSlider1.setName("jSlider1"); // NOI18N

    jProgressBar1.setName("jProgressBar1"); // NOI18N

    jPasswordField1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jPasswordField1.text")); // NOI18N
    jPasswordField1.setName("jPasswordField1"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(371, 371, 371)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 280, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(133, 133, 133))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(233, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(185, 185, 185)
            .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(97, 97, 97))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(486, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(264, 264, 264))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(49, 49, 49)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addGap(62, 62, 62)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 60, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(32, 32, 32))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(446, 446, 446)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(466, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(66, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(46, 46, 46))
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(107, 107, 107)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(56, 56, 56))
    );

    menuBar.setName("menuBar"); // NOI18N

    fileMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("fileMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.setName("fileMenu"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(print.PrintApp.class).getContext().getActionMap(PrintView.class, this);
    exitMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("quit")); // NOI18N
    exitMenuItem.setName("exitMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    helpMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("helpMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.setName("helpMenu"); // NOI18N

    aboutMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("showAboutBox")); // NOI18N
    aboutMenuItem.setName("aboutMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    statusPanel.setName("statusPanel"); // NOI18N

    statusPanelSeparator.setName("statusPanelSeparator"); // NOI18N

    statusMessageLabel.setName("statusMessageLabel"); // NOI18N

    statusAnimationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    statusAnimationLabel.setName("statusAnimationLabel"); // NOI18N

    progressBar.setName("progressBar"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout statusPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(statusPanel);
    statusPanel.setLayout(statusPanelLayout);
    statusPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 975, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 805, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    statusPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
                .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
                .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(3, 3, 3))
    );

    setComponent(mainPanel);
    setMenuBar(menuBar);
    setStatusBar(statusPanel);
}// </editor-fold>                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusAnimationLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel statusPanel;
// End of variables declaration                   

private final Timer messageTimer;
private final Timer busyIconTimer;
private final Icon idleIcon;
private final Icon[] busyIcons = new Icon[15];
private int busyIconIndex = 0;

private JDialog aboutBox;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("PRINT"))
    {
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable(this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok)
        {
            try
            {
              job.print();
            }
            catch (PrinterException ex)
            {
            /* The job did not successfully complete */
            }
        }
    }
}
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now print the window and its visible contents */
   // jPanel1.printAll(g);
    jPanel1.paint(g2d);
    jPanel1.repaint();
    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hmmm, I tried adding the repaint like you had here, but it didn't help.  Still getting a blank page.  Should all this be in the class of the JPanel itself?  Because that's what I'm doing.  I call this.paint(g2d); and this.repaint();

Comment: don't use this. use jpanel.repaint(). This (this) refers to current context. SO if you require to print a jpanel use jpanel.paint(2d); and jpanel.repaint(). I have tried the above and it works.

Comment: Calling jpanel.paint, I get an error from trying to make a static reference to a non-static method.  Are you sure it's not meant to be called on the instance?

Comment: No, I guess it should be then?  That must be the problem, right?

Comment: if u use this your getting a blank page right?? What all components do you have on the panel.

Comment: Well I have three classes: the main one which creates a frame and adds an instance of DrawPanel which is the one I'm trying to print, and an instance of ToolBar which takes the same instance of the DrawPanel in its constructor, and one of the buttons in ToolBar calls print() in the DrawPanel instance (seen above), which calls the overrided method from printable.  There are no components in DrawPanel, but it does display and image and several shapes via the paintComponent method.  Does printing only work for components, and not what the graphics object is displaying?

Comment: I have posted the full class code. The code is actually working for me . Modify it according to your needs.

Comment: printing works for images also. I just tried the same code with mainpanel displaying a image. when i tried to print it does print the image on the mainpanel