# Print JLabel with JTable in desktop application

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, jlabel

How to print JLabel with JTable in Java Standalone application?

I have created GUI in which I added some label and one jable . I want to print this GUI. I also used table API but it print only table. But if I print all the component then all the content of table are not visible.

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.2

Here is code I have used:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Frm1 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame implements Printable,ActionListener{

/**
 * Creates new form Frm1
 */
public Frm1() {
    initComponents();
jButton1.addActionListener(this);


}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jButton1.setText("Print");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("To");

    jLabel2.setText("ABC");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 367,      javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)))
            .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 188, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   

{                                         
MessageFormat format=new MessageFormat("ABC ");
    try {
        jTable1.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, format, format, iconable, null, isSelected, null);
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error");
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration

@Override
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {
  if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now print the window and its visible contents */

    this.printAll(g);

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        jTable1.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311017/java-gui-printing-blank-page/13311280#13311280. Check the print method in the answer

Comment: Print the JLabel, then print the JTable,

Answer (score 1):

First create bufferedImage from your designed base panel or Internal frame..

```
private BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {    
        int w = panel.getWidth();
        int h = panel.getHeight();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        panel.paint(g);
        return bi;
    }
```

Pass the Object of BufferedImage to GraphicsObject of your print API.

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
g2d.drawImage(createImage(this), 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
}
```

Comment: not printg complete jTable and  missing Jlabels too, First column of jtable is not visible in printout.

Comment: It would create image of your panel whatever it is visible on your panel would be printed. If everythings visible in your screen then set the page insets may be your image is larger than your page size(A4).

Comment: You can also use overriden method "drawImage()" to draw large image in a specified area.

Comment: for printing of table header use following line:
        `JTableHeader h = table.getTableHeader();
        h.paint(g);`  after `panel.paint(g)` method.